Splitting-Up Binary Tree Nodes
I am showing the process of inserting alphabetical values into a Red-Black Tree from the string "sethextra".
When I get to the second "t", however, the new node overlaps the "h" node. I.e., I go from this

to this

I could see how this can be fixed by adding manual positioning and arrows from each node to other nodes, but I find it easy to use the child {} / child[missing] nesting method with tikz.
Here's my code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz, multicol, float}

\usetikzlibrary{
   shapes.geometric,
   arrows.meta,
   positioning
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
   seth-extra
\end{center}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
      %level distance=1.25cm, sibling distance=2cm,
      black/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered, fill=black!30},
      red/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered, fill=red!30}
   ]
      \node[black] (s) {s}
      child[missing]
      child[missing];
      \node [above=1pt of s] {add "s"};

      \node[black] (se) [below=1.25cm of s] {s}
      child {
         node[red] {e}
         child[missing]
      }
      child[missing];
      \node [above=1pt of se] {add "e"};

      \node[black] (set) [below=2.50cm of se] {s}
      child {
         node[red] {e}
         child[missing]
      }
      child {
         node[red] {t}
      };
      \node [above=1pt of set] {add "t"};

      \node[black] (seth) [below=2.50cm of set] {s}
      child {
         node[black] {e}
         child[missing]
         child {
            node[red] {h}
         }
      }
      child {
         node[black] {t}
      };
      \node [above=1pt of seth] {add "h"};

      \node[black] (sethe) [below=3.75cm of seth] {s}
      child {
         node[black] {e}
         child{
            node[red] {e}
         }
         child {
            node[red] {h}
         }
      }
      child {
         node[black] {t}
      };
      \node [above=1pt of sethe] {add "e"};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
   \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
      level distance=1.25cm, sibling distance=2cm,
      black/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered, fill=black!30},
      red/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered, fill=red!30}
   ]
   \node[black] (sethex) {s}
   child {
      node[black] {e}
      child{
         node[red] {e}
      }
      child {
         node[red] {h}
      }
   }
   child {
      node[black] {t}
      child[missing]
      child {
         node[red] {x}
      }
   };
   \node [above=1pt of sethex] {add "x"};

   \node[black] (sethext) [below=3.75cm of sethex]{s}
   child {
      node[black] {e}
      child{
         node[red] {e}
      }
      child {
         node[red] {h}
      }
   }
   child {
      node[black] {t}
      child {
         node[red] {t} 
      }
      child {
         node[red] {x}
      }
   };
   \node [above=1pt of sethext] {add "t"};

   \node[black] (sethextr) [below=3.75cm of sethext]{s}
   child {
      node[red] {e}
      child{
         node[black] {e}
      }
      child {
         node[black] {h}
         child[missing]
         child {
            node[red] {r}
         }
      }
   }
   child {
      node[black] {t}
      child {
         node[red] {t} 
      }
      child {
         node[red] {x}
      }
   };
   \node [above=1pt of sethextr] {add "r"};


   \node[black] (sethextra) [below=5.00cm of sethextr]{s}
   child {
      node[red] {e}
      child{
         node[black] {e}
         child {
            node[red] {a}
         }
         child[missing]
      }
      child {
         node[black] {h}
         child[missing]
         child {
            node[red] {r}
         }
      }
   }
   child {
      node[black] {t}
      child {
         node[red] {t} 
      }
      child {
         node[red] {x}
      }
   };
   \node [above=1pt of sethextra] {add "a"};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}

For a reference, I found an online Red-Black Tree generator and want my tree to look similar to below---once completed.


well, I'd use forest or, if not that, some other package for drawing trees which will lay things out a bit more automatically. but you could add a middle phantom to the root's children to force the branches apart.

@cfr Interesting, I've never heard of forest. I'll look into it. Thank you!

This could be more fully automated and the spacing probably needs tweaking, but here's a forest version:

\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/729167/
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in, vmargin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
}
\tikzset{% I think it isn't the best idea to define styles with the same names as colours, since TikZ recognises e.g. red on its own as a colour
  base node/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=1.0cm, inner sep=2pt, text centered,},
  bnode/.style = {base node,fill=black!30},
  rnode/.style = {base node, fill=red!30},
  pnode/.style = {base node, draw=none,fill=none},
}
\forestset{%
  rbtree/.style={%
    for tree={%
      fit=band,
      edge+=-Latex,
    },
    before typesetting nodes={%
      where content={}{pnode,no edge}{},
    },
  },
  alabel/.style={label=above:{add #1}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  seth-extra
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \centering

  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    [s,bnode,alabel=s]
  \end{forest}

  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    [s,bnode,alabel=c [c,rnode][]]
  \end{forest}

  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    [s,bnode,alabel=t [c,rnode][t,rnode]]
  \end{forest}

  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    [s,for tree=bnode,alabel=h [c[][h,rnode]][t]]
  \end{forest}

  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    [s,for tree=bnode,alabel=e [c[e,rnode][h,rnode]][t]]
  \end{forest}


  \columnbreak

  \centering
  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    [s,where n children=0{rnode}{bnode},alabel=x [c[e][h]][t[][x]]]
  \end{forest}

  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    [s,where n children=0{rnode}{bnode},alabel=t [c[e][h]][t[t][x]]]
  \end{forest}

  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    for tree=rnode,
    [s,bnode,alabel=r [c[e,bnode][h[][r]]][t,bnode[t][x]]]
  \end{forest}

  \begin{forest}
    rbtree,
    for tree=rnode
    [s,bnode,alabel=a [c[e,bnode[a][]][h[][r]]][t,bnode[t][x]]]
  \end{forest}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}

